# ServerSocket loses connections without any errors

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm trying to use `SocketServer` to generate web pages, JS scripts and other things. Looks like this:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
while (!stop) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    new Thread() { @Override ...
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        // And here we reading requests and writing responses
    } }.start();
}
```

And most of the times it works. Chrome successfully receives pages from this server.

But! Today I've noticed, that if somebody makes a lot of requests quickly enough - server starts to refuse connection. So Chrome gives me this:

```
net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

On server side I can't see any errors in my try-catch.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you closing the sockets when you're done with them?

Comment: Yep, sockets are being closed, without any errors too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about `InputStream.available()` method returning zero and making me treat requests as empty from time to time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is strange, because you would have to be issuing waaay toooo maaany requests for that to fail.  Perhaps you are not showing us all of your code?

In any case, here is what is probably happening:

The `ServerSocket( int port )` constructor that you are using internally delegates to the `new ServerSocket( int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr )` constructor, passing it the value `50` for `backlog`.  This is the number of connections that can be pending while the server is busy.

The server is busy from the moment the `.accept()` call returns until the next invocation of `.accept()`.  If your server has a lot of work to do between calls to `.accept()`, (i.e. if the call to create a new thread takes a long time,) then the server will be unresponsive during that time, and if enough connections arrive during that time, then any connections past the 50th will be refused.

So, either supply a larger backlog, or, (more likely,) restructure your code so that the server does not take such a long time between calls to `.accept()`.

Comment: Hmm. I think this is not a case. First of all, there's nothing except new thread starting between `accept()`'s. And second - there is much less connections then 50. About 10. Or maybe Chrome doing some extra requests? Anyway, I'll try to increase backlog.

Comment: Nope, didn't help :(

Comment: okay, it was worth a try.  Hope someone comes up with a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

If, for any reason, the network connection between client and server is lost you will be informed of that only when you try to read or write something in the socket.

You need to add code to handle this kind of error and try to establish again a new connection.

Comment: But I always try to read and write something. And I'm getting no errors.

Comment: Network are subject to faults. You can't write a code that establish a socket and be sure that the socket will work always. So in the code is necessary to handle the possibility that the connection will lost.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I don't understand something, but, as I said, I'm getting no errors. How to handle lost connection then?

Comment: When you try to write or read something you will have an error. You need to inspect the error and if it is related to a connection lost you need to create a new Socket (on the client side)

Comment: I can repeat third time, that I always read and write something and getting no errors

Comment: If chrome gives you net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED this is an error. So why you said that you are getting no errors?

Comment: I'm getting no errors on server side. I think, my question is written pretty clearly.

Comment: You don't have an error on server side because you are not trying to read or write on the server side. Imagine that. You establish the connection, no data is sent. Connection is lost. Client try to send something. Client receive an error. Server doesn't receive an error.

Comment: Do you read and write on the connection that has the error on the client side? Or you read and write on other connections?

Comment: Imagine some reading and writing instead of `// And here we reading requests and writing responses` comment. Of course, I'm using streams declared above. I checked it lot of times.

Comment: Sorry I don't give original code, but it has been tested carefully, it's not an issue.